# link_to_remote has no respond for :with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have create a quiz. and using ajax request to change one question per page and i answered using radio button but when i using **:with parameter 'answer='+$('answer').value**.. the link_to_remote doest not respond itself it is in that same page.

```
<div class = "y">
<% form_for @answer do |f|%>
<div class = "label_field_pair">
<label for "questions">
  <%= @ans.ques %>
</label>  
</div> <br>
 <div class = "label_field_pair2">
<label for "options">
  <div id = "option-1">
    <%= radio_button_tag 'answer', 'ans1'%><%= @ans.ans1 %>
  </div><br>
  <div id = "option-2">
    <%= radio_button_tag 'answer', 'ans2'%><%= @ans.ans2 %>
  </div><br>
  <div id = "option-3">
    <%= radio_button_tag 'answer', 'ans3'%><%= @ans.ans3 %>
  </div><br>
  <div id = "option-4">
    <%= radio_button_tag 'answer', 'ans4'%><%= @ans.ans4  %>
  </div><br>
</label>
</div>
<div class="next">

  <%= link_to_remote "Next", 
    :before => "Element.show('loader')",
    :success => "Element.hide('loader')",
    :url=>{:controller=>"answers", :action=>"next"},
    :with => "'answer='+$('answer').value"
  %> 
 </div>
 <% end %>  
 </div>
```

When i not use that answer in:with it works correctly 
can anyone help me please.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass any parameter to that controller you could use :with option.

:with ==> A JavaScript expression specifying the parameters for the XMLHttpRequest. Any expressions should return a valid URL query string.

Example:

```
:with => "'name=' + $('name').value"
```

And in controller you could get like params[:name]

Comment: yes i used that in my code.. but it has no response :with => "'answer='+$('answer').value"

Comment: could you please verify $('answer').value returning value or not?

Comment: how could i verify... the development log and web page does not change it goes to #

Comment: You can verify this in your broswer console ..! are you using Firefox?

Comment: no chrome <input id="answer_ans1" name="answer" type="radio" value="ans1">

Comment: Press F12 and click console tab the paste $('name').value this code

Comment: Please read this https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: try this $('input:radio[name=answer]:checked').val();

Comment: NO to returns the same

Comment: click the radio button and check see this http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/02/get-radio-button-value-using-jquery.html